# jQuery rename id from class elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following html.  Its a table that can contains many rows id=rows_x.

```
<div class="row_table" id="row_1">
<div class="row_table" id="row_2">
<div class="row_table" id="row_3">
<div class="row_table" id="row_4">
```

Then I have id button that once clicked will delete the id ="row_2"

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $('#row_2').remove();
    /* Rename rows id goes here */
}
```

**And now for my question:**

Since row_2 has been removed I need to be able to rename all following rows.

row_3 should become row_2, etc...

Comment: can i ask why you do this? (What is the purpose of those ID's ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $('#row_2').remove();

     // iterates through each of the elements matched by the selector
     $('.row_table').each(
          // i represents the index of each of the elements
          function(i){
              // sets the id of each of the returned elements
              // to the string concatenated with the expression 'i + 1'
              this.id = 'row_' + (i+1);
          });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tA2hm/).

Comment: but row 3 and 4 should become row 2 and 3

Comment: Did you look at the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tA2hm/)? They do. Unless you want to change the text-contents of the rows as well?

Comment: Updated the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tA2hm/1/), to demonstrate the changed `id`.

Comment: Hey, Great work @David could you explain exactly how this works?